# TypeError: Cannot read property 'components' of undefined in Vue2

Tags: vuejs2, mixins

I'm using mixins in the subset components of app.vue without any problems, everything is good and works fine, but when I want to use it into the app.vue component, i'm having error in console.

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable */
import PanelUser from "./layouts/PanelUser";
import Auth from "./mixins/Auth";
export default {
  name: "App",
  mixins: [Auth],
  components: {
    PanelUser
  },
};
</script>
```

[image: error]

I also can not use the router; when I use it, the page is completely white and nothing is displayed.

Comment: I think your router,js has problem ,

Answer (score 14):

I have found how to check this situation.

First, you could see that the error threw at **checkComponents** method, move your mouse on and left click.

[image]

Second, add a **break point**, and then refresh the page.

[image]

Third, maybe you could find that **some mixins or components which are referenced show undefined**.
In my case, the second mixin is undefind.

[image]

Finally, **check the reference or the mixin file**. I found the reason is that I copied the mixin from another file and forgot to rename the mixin at declare part.

[image]

That's all, try to check by yourself. :)

Comment: I would like to point out this response as a good example of helpful and instructional. Thank you for taking the time to write out this response.

Answer (score 6):

You need to change:

> import PanelUser from "./layouts/PanelUser";
>
> To
>
> import {PanelUser} from "./layouts/PanelUser";

And

> import Auth from "./mixins/Auth";
>
> To
>
> import {Auth} from "./mixins/Auth";

Answer (score 6):

The error is **mixin** related.

Make sure your mixins being used in your components are correct. (eg. name, esm import path etc.)

```
import samplePackage from "sample-package";
import anotherMixin from "another-package/path/to/mixin";

export default {
    mixins: [
        samplePackage.sampleMixin,
        anotherMixin
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a couple hours of debugging, I found in our case the culprit was `vuelidate`. We tried to migrate from Webpack to **Vite**, keeping **Vue 2.7**, and **vuelidate 3**.

Importing:

```js
import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate'
console.log(validationMixin // undefined in production build
```

printed only `undefined` after a `vite build`

After reading about issues related to non-ESM imports ([#1](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4083), [#2](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6061)) I tried to change the import to vuelidate/src:

```js
import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate/src/index'
console.log(validationMixin) // works!

// import the validators from "lib" though, src threw an require-js error for me
import { required, email, minLength } from "vuelidate/lib/validators"
```